# ggplot: labes are doubled in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a horizontal, stacked bar chart. I want to label each part of the bar with the corresponding number (count). Those labels appear twice and I don't now why. How can I make "92" etc. appear only once?
[image: lables doubled]

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)

data2 <- data.frame(System=rep(c('participants opinion'), each=5),
                    attitude=rep(c('totally agree','agree somewhat','unsure','disagree somewhat','totally disagree'), times=2),
                    count=c(92, 83, 22, 17, 6))

data2$attitude = factor(data2$attitude, levels = c('unsure','totally disagree','disagree somewhat','agree somewhat','totally agree'))
data2 = arrange(data2, System, desc(attitude))
data2 = ddply(data2, .(System), transform, pos = (cumsum(count) - 0.5 * count))
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#2A7AD4", "#5C96D7", "#D3A253", "#D48F1D")

ggplot(data2, aes(x = factor(System), y = count, fill = attitude)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .3) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos, label = count), size = 4) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)
```

Comment: This is a typo, when you are creating a data2, attitude column gets twice as long, so other column rows repeat., remove rep from attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `data2` object has 2 rows for every count, if you remove one row of each by:

```
label_data <- data2 |> 
  split(~count) |> 
  purrr::map_dfr(~.x |> head(1))
```

and putting it into:

```
geom_text(data = label_data, aes(y = pos, label = count), size = 4)
```

you can avoid that

Comment: you can also play with the `label_data` in case you want to have the last line, or the mean of both rows,....